# Is it possible to parse a text file using Rust's csv crate?

Tags: csv, rust

I have a text file with multiple lines. Is it possible to use Rust's [csv crate](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.4/csv/) to parse it such that each line is parsed into a different record?

I've tried specifying `b'\n'` as the field delimiter and left the record terminator as the default. The issue I'm having is that lines can sometimes end with `\r\n` and sometimes with just `\n`.
This however raises the [`UnequalLengths`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0-beta.5/csv/enum.ErrorKind.html) error unless the `flexible` option is specified because apparently new lines take precedence over field delimiters, so the code below:

```
use csv::{ByteRecord, Reader as CsvReader, ReaderBuilder, Terminator};

fn main() { 
    let data = "foo,foo2\r\nbar,bar2\nbaz\r\n";
    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\n')
        .has_headers(false)
        .flexible(true)
        .from_reader(data.as_bytes());
    let mut record = ByteRecord::new();
    loop {
        match reader.read_byte_record(&mut record) {
            Ok(true) => {},
            Ok(false) => { break },
            Err(csv_error) => {
                println!("{}", csv_error);
                break;
            }
        }
        println!("fields: {}", record.len());
        for field in record.iter() {
            println!("{:?}", ::std::str::from_utf8(&field))
        }
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
fields: 1
Ok("foo,foo2")
fields: 2
Ok("bar,bar2")
Ok("baz")
```

I would like the string to be parsed into 3 records with one field each, so the expected output would be:

```
fields: 1
Ok("foo,foo2")
fields: 1
Ok("bar,bar2")
fields: 1
Ok("baz")
```

Is it possible to tweak the CSV reader somehow to obtain that behavior?

Conceptually I'd like the field terminator to be `None` but it seems that the terminator must be a single `u8` value

Comment: *Is it possible to use Rust's csv crate to parse it such that each line is parsed into a different record?* That is how CSV files normally work. Are you asking if it's possible to parse it such that each line is a different *field*?

Comment: Wait, wait... *I would like the string to be parsed into 3 records with one field each.* Then why did you change the *field* delimiter to `\n`? Don't you get what you want if you just remove the `.delimiter(b'\n')` line?

Comment: @trentcl I meant that I'd like each line to get parsed into a different record regardless of commas or any other delimiters. I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: Could you please also provide expected/desired output, so that we can conclude when we have answered the question?

Comment: Ok... so why are you using `csv` at all, if you don't need field separators? I'm a bit confused by this question because it seems like a problem that doesn't exist. Like, if you asked, "How do I blunt my scissors so I don't cut myself on the treadmill?" A logical follow up would be "why carry scissors on a treadmill at all?"

Comment: @trentcl Because new lines can still appear inside quoted fields and the csv crate already knows how to handle it and also we're using it all over the place for parsing different formats (csv,psv,hsv, etc.) so the most natural thing will be using it with a custom separator

Comment: @TheCoolDrop added

Comment: I'm the author of the csv crate and I don't think you should be using the csv crate for this task. This question has made me realize that the csv parser should orobably return an error (or panic) if callers set the delimiter and record separator to the same thing. So, I'd aay the answer to your question is: "maybe, but it is not guaranteed to work and is a misuse of the crate." Just parse your format by hand.

Comment: *new lines can still appear inside quoted fields* — your post has **nothing** about quoting; how would anyone know that's an important feature?

Comment: @Shepmaster true but how is that relevant to whether the crate can be used for that task?

Comment: I don't know how to respond to that... Your **comment** indicates that it's important that newlines inside of quotes are treated differently from newlines outside of quotes, but _your **post** doesn't say that_. If it's an important requirement, you need to include it! Otherwise, as mentioned earlier, how can we conclude when we have answered the question?

Comment: Otherwise the answer is "use the `lines` method" and don't use a crate at all.

Comment: @Shepmaster the comment was answering why I want to use the crate, the post is asking if it’s possible to use the crate. I’m very satisfied with a plain “no” which would justify coding my own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll re-post my comment as the answer. More succinctly, as the author of the `csv` crate, I'd say the answer to your question is "no."

Firstly, it's not clear to me why you're trying to use a csv parser for this task at all. As the comments indicate, it's likely that your question is under-specified. Nevertheless, it seems more prudent to just write your own parser.

Secondly, setting both the delimiter and the terminator to the same thing is probably a condition in which the csv reader should panic or return an error. It doesn't really make sense from the perspective of the parser, and its behavior is likely unspecified.

Finally, it seems to me like your desired output indicates that you should just [iterate over the lines in your input](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines). It should give you exactly the output you want, as it handles both `\n` and `\r\n`.